# numpy ravel function return issue

Tags: python, numpy

When ravel() returns a contiguous 1D array of all the elements in nD array, I observed it just returned only unique elements of X1 as mentioned. Am I missing anything?

```html
tst
Out[44]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])

tst.ravel()
Out[45]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4])

X1
Out[46]: 
array([[-2.99318916, -2.98318916, -2.97318916, ...,  3.13681084,
         3.14681084,  3.15681084],
       [-2.99318916, -2.98318916, -2.97318916, ...,  3.13681084,
         3.14681084,  3.15681084],
       [-2.99318916, -2.98318916, -2.97318916, ...,  3.13681084,
         3.14681084,  3.15681084],
       ..., 
       [-2.99318916, -2.98318916, -2.97318916, ...,  3.13681084,
         3.14681084,  3.15681084],
       [-2.99318916, -2.98318916, -2.97318916, ...,  3.13681084,
         3.14681084,  3.15681084],
       [-2.99318916, -2.98318916, -2.97318916, ...,  3.13681084,
         3.14681084,  3.15681084]])

X1.ravel()
Out[47]: 
array([-2.99318916, -2.98318916, -2.97318916, ...,  3.13681084,
        3.14681084,  3.15681084])
```

Comment: Does `X1.size == X1.ravel().size`?  Those ellipses mean there’s a bunch of numbers in between.

Comment: Check the length of the result. I would guess that the  `...,` is hiding most of your numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a printing issue.
You can tune this behavior with `numpy.set_printoptions`:

```
In [404]: np.array([arange(10)]*10).ravel()
Out[404]: 
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2,
       3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
       6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
       9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1,
       2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [405]: np.set_printoptions(threshold=90)

In [406]: np.array([arange(10)]*10).ravel()
Out[406]: array([0, 1, 2, ..., 7, 8, 9])
```